# Do squad members benefit from the enhanced scope weapon modification?

Tags: mass-effect-3

ME3 squad members don't run out of ammo nor are they affected by weight. However do squad members see through smoke when equipped with the enhanced scope weapon mod?

Comment: If they're anything like NPC enemies, they don't even notice smoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I, nor can anyone else answer the question that you asked, but I know what answer works as well: NPCs, even in a very emotional and psychologically based game like ME3, are still NPCs and do not have advanced artificial intelligence. From what I've seen in game, they don't get affected by smoke, they just keep on going on the right track. I don't think that your scope mod will help, due to the fact that they aren't even affected by smoke to begin with.