# Can my squad mates see through smoke?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Centurions like to chuck smoke grenades in my squad's face like punks. While it definitely puts a damper on [my visibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/how-can-i-see-through-smoke), it [does not seem to have an effect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55934/can-enemies-see-me-through-smoke) on the Centurions themselves. The only other subjects left to subject to smoke are my squad mates.

**Can my squad mates see through smoke?** Does it affect them in any way, or do they ignore it and continue to suppress the enemies with [their uncanny combat skills](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54297/has-the-suicidal-squad-mate-ai-behavior-on-higher-difficulties-been-fixed)? If they can see through the smoke, *why don't I get a cool pair of smoke goggles too?*

Answer (score 3):

"Equipping companions with the Particle Rifle makes easy to focus-fire enemies. The AI also ignores smoke grenades (and sometimes even solid obstacles) so your companions will pinpoint enemies you can't see. "

[Source](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Particle_Rifle)

I've personally seen this tactic to work, so the answer is yes.

> If they can see through the smoke, why don't I get a cool pair of
>   smoke goggles too?

You can't get smoke goggles but there is a Sniper Rifle Enhanced Scope weapon upgrade that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

In my games they keep shooting through the smoke so I'd say they can but that's only empirical evidence. We can't know for sure unless the devs themselves shed some light on it.

[Here is a similar answer to a similar question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56055/13314)

Answer (score 0):

No absolute evidence to back it up, but it seems from my game that they can in fact see through smoke.  You can also aim through it with the enhanced scope mod, though I'm uncertain how effectively as I've never used it.